# To learn ASP MVC should I learn C# first?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make web apps. Should I start with a ASP MVC books or first with C# books, due ASP MVC is written in this language.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have programming experience with other languages?

Comment: If you have experience with other programming languages like Java, you'll find C# syntactically similar and easy to pick up. If that's true I'd definitely dive straight in with MVC.

Comment: Yes. I have programming experience with other languages like c++, java and python. Thank you!

Comment: there are some features of C# you will have to learn (like lambda and closure, generics or linq) but otherwise you will be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely definitely and without any hesitation you should first learn the .NET framework by picking a CLS language such as C# or VB.NET before getting into ASP.NET MVC. Once you learn .NET, depending on your level of experience of web development in general you might start by learning the HTTP protocol and some markup such as HTML. I have seen many developers starting to work with ASP.NET MVC without knowing anything about the HTTP protocol which is at the base of every web application. Javascript comes next.

Once you are familiar with those concepts you could jump into ASP.NET MVC. At least that's the advice I can give you. If you have no experience with .NET and you start directly with ASP.NET MVC that would be very counter productive.

Comment: +1 for suggesting HTTP protocol. The downside and upside of .NET technologies is the ability for new developers to start developing without knowing anything about underneath.

Comment: @justnS, yes the knowing HTTP protocol is absolutely fundamental in order to develop web applications no matter what underlying technology you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should learn C# first. Especially if you have no prior programming language. If you already know an OO language, it might not be *that* important to study C# first, but I would definitely recommend you to read a book on it, or use tutorials and practice, before diving into MVC.

MVC is a framework. You write code for it in one of the .NET languages, such as C# or VB.NET. If you can't code C# at a basic level (or one of it's friends), MVC, the book and its examples, will make no sense to you.